# Java Executor Service - Multiple Threads - Insert If not Exists Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have 10 threads in my thread pool and am executing a task depending upon its entry in the mysql. The problem is that if the entry exists in the mysql database there is no need for processing and the control will return from there.

I have used unique constraint in the table but how can I handle it in the application level?

Other than catcin`sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception` is there any way out?

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: what have you done so far??

Comment: stuck - how do i handle it in my application except catching `sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception`

Comment: Can't you select first and then try inserting? If the probability of finding a row is high, then, it will reduce the insert failures. won't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways but each method has its pros and cons.

1) Store the primary key or unique constraint you set in the database in memory. You can always check whether the entry is already exists or not before inserting the record. In this case, we have to make sure that no records are inserted into database through back door (all the records to be inserted or updated through your application). Also, it will also consume a considerable amount of memory when your database grows larger and larger.

2) Query the database before inserting the records. This is the safest way but there will be two operations (select & insert) for inserting a new record.

3) Blindly Insert the record. In this case, the integrity exception will be thrown and it should be handled properly.

Keeping all the pros and cons in the above methods, the option "3" seems like a better solution for me but you can decide based on your need.

Comment: Thanks, does make sense

Answer (score 0):

Use separate connections in each task of you thread.
Use Statement.getUpdateCount() or int insertCount=statement.executeUpdate(...)